# Poetry/Meson: How to use meson as a build backend with Cython files to install a Python/Cython package

Tags: python, cython, python-poetry, meson-build

I have a Python package that contains Cython code, similar to scikit-learn. I am trying to use poetry to do package management, but meson to handle the build process for Cython and possible c++ code. Before, when I was using the deprecated setuptools and distutils, I was able to do the following in scikit-learn:

```
pip install -e .
```

which built the Cython files and allowed them to be importable by sklearn's Python files. For example `from _criterion import Criterion` works, where `_criterion.pxd/pyx` is a Cython file that contains some variable named `Criterion`.

Now I am using poetry and meson and things do not work.

### My Goals to Use Poetry and Meson

I would ideally like to be able to just do `poetry install` (or `poetry build` and `poetry install`), which should build and install things by using Meson to build local Cython/C++ files and then use poetry to handle other pip installable Python packages.

### My Question

How do I correctly use poetry with meson to build my Cython files and install them along with other relevant Python dependencies to install my package?

### My Attempt using just Meson incorrectly Cython files to the wrong environment

I instantiated my meson.build files such that running `meson build` in my repo's root directory works:

```
The Meson build system
Version: 0.63.2
Source dir: /Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree
Build dir: /Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/build
Build type: native build
Project name: scikit-tree
Project version: 0.0.0.dev0
C compiler for the host machine: arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang (clang 14.0.6 "clang version 14.0.6")
C linker for the host machine: arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang ld64 609
C++ compiler for the host machine: arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ (clang 14.0.6 "clang version 14.0.6")
C++ linker for the host machine: arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ ld64 609
Host machine cpu family: aarch64
Host machine cpu: arm64
Library m found: YES
Program cython found: YES (/Users/adam2392/miniforge3/envs/sktree/bin/cython)
Program python3 found: YES (/Users/adam2392/miniforge3/envs/sktree/bin/python3)
Message: /Users/adam2392/miniforge3/envs/sktree/bin/python3
Message: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
Found pkg-config: /opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
Program _build_utils/cythoner.py found: YES (python /Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/sktree/_build_utils/cythoner.py)
Build targets in project: 1

scikit-tree 0.0.0.dev0

  User defined options
    backend: ninja

Found ninja-1.11.1 at /opt/homebrew/bin/ninja
```

When I then run `meson install` within the `build/` directory:

```
(sktree) adam2392@Adams-MacBook-Pro build % meson install
ninja: Entering directory `/Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/build'
[3/3] Linking target sktree/tree/_unsup_criterion.cpython-39-darwin.so
ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
Installing sktree/tree/_unsup_criterion.cpython-39-darwin.so to /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktree/tree
Installing /Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/sktree/__init__.py to /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktree
Installing /Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/sktree/_forest.py to /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktree
Installing /Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/sktree/tree/__init__.py to /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktree/tree
Installing /Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/sktree/tree/_classes.py to /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktree/tree
```

which installs for example the Cython files into the incorrect Python environment (i.e. home-brew). I need it to be installed in my virtual environment.

### My Attempt using Poetry doesn't work either

My `pyproject.toml` file has the following lines:

```
[build-system]
build-backend = "mesonpy"
requires = [
    "meson-python>=0.11.0",
    # `wheel` is needed for non-isolated builds, given that `meson-python`
    # doesn't list it as a runtime requirement (at least in 0.10.0)
    # See https://github.com/FFY00/meson-python/blob/main/pyproject.toml#L4
    "wheel",
    "setuptools<=65.5",
    "packaging",
    "Cython>=0.29.24",
    "scikit-learn",
]
```

However, when I run `poetry install`, there are no errors, but:

```
python -c "from sktree import tree"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/sktree/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import tree
  File "/Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/sktree/tree/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._classes import UnsupervisedDecisionTree
  File "/Users/adam2392/Documents/scikit-tree/sktree/tree/_classes.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ._unsup_criterion import UnsupervisedCriterion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sktree.tree._unsup_criterion'
```